# Extract all the values of a key based on the primary key id in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, list, ordereddictionary

I have a list of Ordered dictionary like below:

```
l = [OrderedDict([(u'id', u'5'), (u'name', u'Jack')]), OrderedDict([(u'id', 
u'6'), (u'name', u'Steve')]),...]
```

where id is the primary key. For every dicitonary in the list I want to extract and store only the name items corresponding to each id, how to do it?

with the below code:

```
li = []
for item in l:
    res = li.append(item['name'])
    print res
```

It results None

**Edit:**
Expected result:

```
['Jack', 'Steve',...]
```

'Jack' should be corresponding to id=5, 'Steve' for id=6 and so on

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: your code doesn't make sense. Please edit your question with a minimal reproducible example, actual results and expected results.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Added

Comment: just loop over items and get the 2nd element of a list

Comment: ...and I am not sure that you `OrderedDict` construction is correct.

Comment: @mikuszefski just corrected it.

Comment: Ok...but is this a high degree oversimplification of your real problem or why you do not use `OrderedDict( [(u'id', u'5'), (u'name', u'Jack'), (u'id', 
u'6'), (u'name', u'Steve') ] )` or even something like `OrderedDict( [ (u'id 5', u'name Jack'), ( u'id 6', u'name Steve' ), ... ] )` without the list of dictionaries, as I don't see the point of those at the moment.

Comment: and by the way, just remove the indent from the `print` and make it `print( li )` not `res`